# php preg_replace any text + a slash if there is one

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

**Types:**

```
$str = 'folder';
$str = 'folder/subfolder';
```

**Desired Result:**

```
$str = '';
$str = 'subfolder';
```

**Attempt:**

```
// Works for "folder/subfolder"
$str = preg_replace('/.*?\//i', '', $str);
```

**NOTE:** "folder" is unknown.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('#^[^/]+/?#', '', 'folder');
```

should work. This removes non-slash characters at the start of the string (a folder name) and a slash after that (or not, if the folder name is isolated).

Comment: And if there is another slash in the front of "folder"?

Comment: Then you can put `/?` after the first `^`.